# Better solution than a switch statement

Tags: javascript, loops, refactoring, switch-statement

Below is a function that extracts a month from an array in a loop. When a month is found the month get iterated by 1 in the object CRIMES_PER_MONTH.

This works, but it's quite an ugly solution and the switch statement get very long. So, what can I use instead of the switch statement?

```
var crimes_per_month = {
          january: 0,
          february: 0,
          mars: 0,
          april: 0,
          may: 0,
          june: 0,
          july: 0,
          august: 0,
          september: 0,
          oktober: 0,
          november: 0,
          december: 0
};

function AddToMonths(month) {

    switch(month) {

        case 1:
            jan += 1;
        break;

        case 2:
            feb += 1;
        break;

        case 3:
            mar += 1;
        break;

        case 4:
            apr += 1;
        break;

        ... and so on...

    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < incidents.length; i++) {
    month = incidents[i].substring(5, 7);
    AddToMonths(parseInt(month));
}
```

I suppose the best thing would be to access the object directly in the loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < incidents.length; i++) {
    month = incidents[i].substring(5, 7);
    crimes_per_month[month] += 1;
}
```

...but this ony works for arrays, and I really want to keep this as an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easiest to make `crimes_per_month` an array so that its properties can be directly addressed with the key that `addToMonths` is given:

```
crimes_per_month = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
function addToMonths(month) {
    crimes_per_month[month-1] += 1;
}
```

If you don't want that, you will need to make an index-to-monthname conversion function.

```
var crimes_per_month = {
    january: 0,
    february: 0,
    mars: 0,
    april: 0,
    may: 0,
    june: 0,
    july: 0,
    august: 0,
    september: 0,
    oktober: 0,
    november: 0,
    december: 0
};

function addToMonths(month) {
    var names = ["january", "february", "mars", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"];
    var name = names[month-1];
    crimes_per_month[name] += 1;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert the array to an object after this is done? I really need to have it as an object.

Comment: Of course you can. Just map the values on an object, and use the index-to-name conversion to get the property names.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use an array.

```
var crime_per_month = new Array(13);
for(var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) crime_per_month[i] = 0;
function AddToMonths(month) {
    crime_per_month[month]++;
}
```

Comment: Since when do years have 13 months?

Comment: he wants months from 1 to 12, but the first element in array is 0, so he needs 13 elements... Duh!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the goal is typically to transpose a set back to a 0-based array, rather than attempting to pad a 0-indexed set to match the bounds of the problem...

Answer (score 2):

If you like to keep current `CRIMES_PER_MONTH` structure, you can use array with keys to translate month number to key name:

```
var addToMonths = (function () {
    var names = ["january", "february", "mars", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "oktober", "november", "december"];
    return function (month) {
        CRIMES_PER_MONTH[names[month - 1]]++;
    };
}());
```

Comment: Objects have no order, so you cannot be sure the get the correct indices. Nice closure, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just have an array of month-names, which you look up.

```
var months = ["january", "february", ...],
    month = incidents[i].substring(...),

    incident_month = months[month-1]; // case 1: === "january"

 crimes_per_month[incident_month] += 1; // case 1: === crimes_per_month.january += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

did I miss something obviously here?

It's JavaScript, so (almost) everything is allowed ;)

Why don't you just access the object members? 
You would need the same member name in `crimes_per_month` and `incidents_month` and should be able to just do something like:

```
var crimes_per_month = {january: 0,...};
var incidents_month = {january: 14,....};

function addToMonth(/* string */ monthName) {
  crimes_per_month[monthName] = crimes_per_month[monthName] + 1;
}
```